# How to manage different release versions of a Google Appscript Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I developed a Google AppScript AddOn using clasp for pushing it to the AppScript Project.

Now I want to push a *similar* version to a different AppScript project, which should have the same code base but following changes:

- different scriptId obviously
- different appscript.json ( or at least parts of it should be different)
- some strings inside the code should be different
- some UI elements should be excluded

My current idea looks like this:

Use a bash script of `google/zx` to create a deploy script which changes the scriptId and appscript.json before pushing via clasp.

For variables I would just add a dictionary for each release configuration, and the UI elements the only solution I can think of is to have a conditional statement to check which release configuration is used and exclude it.

I would like to set this release configuration based on a value in the `ScriptProperies` but I also would like set this value when deploying, but how? Afaik you can not set properties in the `appsscript.json`.

Overall this approach is not very nice and I hope that someone can give me some input for improvements.